# Differentially sampling integers using threshold value

Tags: r

I am using `sample()` to  draw 1000 integers ranging from 1 to 120. I expect roughly 77% of them to fall below a threshold of 65. (i.e, 77% sampled uniformly between 1-65, with the remaining 23% sampled uniformly from 66-120).

I can do this in a clunky fashion by specifying each probability for 1 to 120:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
mmax <- 120
thresh <- 65
probthresh <- 0.77

x <- sample(1:mmax, n,
            prob = c(rep(probthresh/thresh, thresh), 
                     rep((1 - probthresh)/(mmax - thresh), (mmax - thresh))),
            replace = TRUE)
table(x <= thresh)

# FALSE  TRUE 
#   226   774
```

As you can see the `prob` statement is quite inelegant and may not scale up safely in more complex applications.

How can I more appropriately draw integers in this context according to these constraints? I do not necessarily need to use `sample()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @MrFlick:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
mmax <- 120
thresh <- 65
probthresh <- 0.77

x <- sample(1:thresh, floor(n * probthresh), replace = TRUE) %>% #77% of integers below the threshold
  c(sample((thresh + 1):mmax, n - length(.), replace = TRUE)) #remaining integers uniformly from 66-120
  
table(x <= thresh)

FALSE  TRUE 
  230   770
```

Answer (score 2):

You could conditionally choose between two samples with some probability.

```
x <- ifelse(runif(n) < probthresh, 
  sample(1:thresh, n, replace=TRUE), 
  sample((thresh+1):mmax, n, replace=TRUE)
)
```